# ¿Método onClick de ArrayList<>?

Tags: java, android

Tengo lo siguiente que será una `ListView` (Está en un `Fragment`) :

```
 final ArrayList<User> allBoxerData= new ArrayList<User>();

    allBoxerData.add(new User("Ramon \nDekkers",R.drawable.ramonfinalmej));
    allBoxerData.add(new User("Sergio \nMartínez",R.drawable.sergiomej1));
    allBoxerData.add(new User("Kiko \nMartínez",R.drawable.kikomej1));
    allBoxerData.add(new User("Roberto \nSantos",R.drawable.robertofinal));
    allBoxerData.add(new User("Dani \nCuevas",R.drawable.danimej1));
    allBoxerData.add(new User("Roman \nVardanyan",R.drawable.romanfinal));
    allBoxerData.add(new User("Ivan \nSalcines",R.drawable.ivanred));
    allBoxerData.add(new User("Eva María \nNaranjo",R.drawable.evacuadrado));
    allBoxerData.add(new User("Manzy \nPauwells",R.drawable.manzymej1));
    allBoxerData.add(new User("Lara \nMartín",R.drawable.laramej1));
    allBoxerData.add(new User("Antonio \nRodríguez",R.drawable.antoniomej));
    allBoxerData.add(new User("Katharina \nThanderz",R.drawable.katmej1));


    mylist = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.mylist);

    usersAdapter = new UsersAdapter(getActivity(),allBoxerData);


////  AQUI ES DONDE ME HACE FALTA SABER COMO HACER EL ONCLICK, DEPENDIENDO QUE ELEMENTO DE LA LISTA HAGO CLICK ME LLEVE A UN FRAGMENT DISTINTO.

    mylist.setAdapter(usersAdapter);
    usersAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                final int position, long id) {
           //Log.i("List View Clicked", "**********");


            if (position==1) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Listttt View Clicked:" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Tengo puesto en position 1 como diciendo la posicion 1 del `ListView`, como desesperación ya, porque no sé como ponerlo. Necesito que dependiendo del elemento de la lista que se seleccione, me lleve a un `Fragment` distinto, lo que me falta es en la comparación del "if" poner algo válido.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47785/discussion-on-question-by-rf-mvs--metodo-onclick-de-arraylist).

Comment: ¿Existe algún patrón de a que fragmento debe llevarte cada elemento?,

Answer (score 2):

Hazlo con un Switch y pregunta la posición del fragment para abrir uno u otro fragment.

```
int itm=arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
  switch (itm) {
            case 0:
            Fragment newFragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
    transaction.commit();
            case 1:
             ....
                 break;
            case 2:
              break;
}
```